# Symfony error handling for both website and REST API of website

Tags: web-services, api, error-handling, symfony1

I have a symfony project.

There is a website and a rest API that projects all the actions that can be done on the website.

I would like to manage the data handling (get, update, delete) for both website and API on the same code.

I realized that I need to put all the code in the MODEL so that it will be accessible via the API module and the website modules.

How do I handle errors in an Elegant way for both componenets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would either:

- **Throw exceptions in the model methods**. The exceptions can contain the message of what went wrong and your API actions / standard module actions can handle the exceptions as necessary.
- **Return success/failure codes**. Have your delete/update/get methods return various codes indicating what could have possibly gone wrong. Alternatively, you could return true/false and have some sort of `getLastError` method.